# Application openURL gets called a few seconds after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, deep-linking, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a deep linking feature in my app that works fine beside one case.
I have a 3 different onboarding pages according to the url that opened the app.
So when the app is launched i need to know what link(if any) opened the app and then present the right onboarding page. The problem is that i need to know what screen to present in the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

but i can only know if a deep link opened the app in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

which gets called 5 seconds after did `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called(i counted the seconds). So i have 5 seconds that i see a wrong onboarding page untill `openURL` is called(if it will be called) .

So my question is: is there any way to know if the app was launched from a url before or during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

By the way `launchOptions` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is nil when the app opens from a deep link

Comment: Hello aviv_eik I am also implementing same feature & facing same problem. Can you please help me to sort it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

The launch option key your are looking for is **`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`** (Objective-C) / **`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url`** (Swift).
If you're targeting iOS 9 and upwards you only have to intercept a launch URL from

- `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (in case the app is not in memory yet)
- `application:openURL:options:` (in case the app is already in the background).

Here's a minimalistic implementation of `UIApplicationDelegate` that should cover both cases - please note that a lot unrelated logic has been omitted for clarity:

Objective-C:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSURL *url = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url) {
        // TODO: handle URL from here
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    // TODO: handle URL from here

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Swift 5:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
            // TODO: handle URL from here
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        // TODO: handle URL from here

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: when i open my app from a deeplink 'launchOptions' is nil in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but 'openURL' does gets triggerd (with the deep link url). I do show my onboarding page inside 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions', where do you think i should show the first key window when the app launched

Comment: Ok let me ask a few other questions: Are you opening your app from a web browser? What minimum iOS version are you targeting?  

Note that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is only called once per run time. If your app is already in the background, application:openURL:options: will be called instead.  

My comment regarding window setup only applies if you rely on a storyboard as the 'Main Interface' setting. If you're setting up the interface yourself from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you'll be fine, please ignore the comment.

Comment: I improved my answer for clarity - it has been tested with Xcode 8.3 on devices running iOS 9.3.4 and iOS 10.3, for both Objective-C and Swift builds.  Make sure you did set a value in your `Info.plist`'s `URL Types` > `URL Schemes` (e.g. "my-app"), build the app on your device then kill it, then try to open e.g. "my-app://" in any web browser.

Comment: although this is an old question by the time I am writing the comments, still wanted to warn new readers that it is not necessary to handle URL both in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application(_:open:options:)`. It is enough to check just on `application(_:open:options:)`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation

Comment: yep. @KutayDemireren seems to be right - application(_:open:options:) is called even if app was killed before

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar problem in iOS 13, but things have changed in iOS 13 because the [UIWindowSceneDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate) has been introduced and may now do some of the work previously done by `UIApplicationDelegate` (depending on your app settings).

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42348138/4978732) by @Olivier in this thread was still very useful to me because it points out the two scenarios in which the URL scheme gets handled; namely when the app is not in memory yet, which calls for `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and when the app has already been loaded and is in the background, which second case calls for `application:openURL:options:`.

So, as I'm mentioning above, things are a little different since iOS 13 if you are using the default application template generated by XCode 11. I won't get into the details here, so here's an informative tutorial on the topic: [Understanding the iOS 13 Scene Delegate](https://www.donnywals.com/understanding-the-ios-13-scene-delegate/).

But the key methods to modify if you are using the new approach with scenes are `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene)) and `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene)). The former is where to act upon the URL scheme when the app was not already loaded (so it kind of replaces `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`), and the latter is where to get the URL when the app was already in the background when the URL scheme was called (so this one replaces `application:openURL:options:`).

With `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`, you can look for the URL of the URL scheme (if any) doing something like this:

```
if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url {
    // handle
}
```

For `scene(_:openURLContexts:)`, you can look inside the `URLContexts` set.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

nice idea from previous.
I made some tests..

I confirm iOS 13 odds and bugs.

Preamble:
I enabled all flags on plist:
(from  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118932)

...
     UIFileSharingEnabled
     
     LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace
     
     UISupportsDocumentBrowser
     
..
And added ALL types in plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>abc File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.example.app.document.abc</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>


<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>abc File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>org.example.app.document.abc</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>abc</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I logged here:

1)

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        print(documentsDir())

        if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
            // TODO: handle URL from here
            openWriteAndCloseLog(msg: "1 " + url.absoluteString, withTimestamp: true)
        }
        return true
    }
```

2)

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // TODO: handle URL from here
    openWriteAndCloseLog(msg: "2 " + url.absoluteString, withTimestamp: true)
    return true
}
```

3)

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { 
    if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url {
        // handle
        openWriteAndCloseLog(msg: "3 " + url.absoluteString, withTimestamp: true)            
    }
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

seems we pass ONLY on 3 (as per my debug log I can see inside documents, as I shared via iTunes)

I made a small demo app to test it.

https://github.com/ingconti/DocumentBroswerSampleApp

You can open attachment from (mal for example..)
You will see:

[image]